# Delete an element with index in an array-CloudFirestore

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am trying to delete an element that's inside an array. Below is the structure of my collection

```
Items:
-----subGroupId
---------------[0]
------------------itemName
------------------itemPrice
---------------[1]
------------------itemName
------------------itemPrice
---------------[2]
------------------itemName
------------------itemPrice
```

Before deleting i am experimenting to get the item at a particular index. But i am getting "undefined" when logged.

```
this.db.collection<any>("items").doc(this.subGroupData.sgId).collection("items").doc("/0").valueChanges().subscribe(data=>{
              console.log(data);
            })
```

I expect the output be an object of the item data.

please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out this example from [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) using `.arrayRemove()`

Comment: I'm having a hard time understand your database structure.  Are you saying each document's unique ID is a number?  It might help if you also show a screenshot from the console to help illustrate what you're working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be mixing up subcollections with array fields.  They are not the same thing.

If you have a field of a document which is an array, you can't treat it like a subcollection.  The only way to delete an array field element by index is by reading the document, modifying the array in memory, and updating the array field back to the document.